# How can I match everything that is after the last occurrence of some char in a perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

For example, return the part of the string that is after the last `x` in `axxxghdfx445` (should return `445`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
my($substr) = $string =~ /.*x(.*)/;
```

From perldoc perlre:

> By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will match
>          as many times as possible (given a particular starting location) while
>          still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.

That's why `.*x` will match up to the last occurence of `x`.

Comment: I suggest going with [reko_t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439153/3291390) to [avoid using the greedy `.*`](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/03/why-using-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want).

Comment: Why? It's actually much slower. In this particular case, no backtracking ever happens. Perl either uses the last occurence of `'x'` (aka the floating substr) to determine the start position for the group, or declares no match if there's no `'x'`.

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way would be to use `/([^x]*)$/`

Answer (score 7):

the first answer is a good one,
but when talking about "something that does not contain"...
i like to use the regex that "matches" it

```
my ($substr) = $string =~ /.*x([^x]*)$/;
```

very usefull in some case

Comment: You don't need the leading '.*x' in the regex.

Comment: that's right, thanks, but that was to illustrate the "something that doeas not contain x"

Answer (score 6):

the simplest way is not regular expression, but a simple split() and getting the last element.

```
$string="axxxghdfx445";
@s = split /x/ , $string;
print $s[-1];
```

Comment: Is it really worth it to create a temporary array? `print (split /x/, $string)[-1];` would work just as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way to do it. It's not as simple as a single regular expression, but if you're optimizing for speed, this approach will probably be faster than anything using regex, including `split`.

```
my $s     = 'axxxghdfx445';
my $p     = rindex $s, 'x';
my $match = $p < 0 ? undef : substr($s, $p + 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the special variable that does this, `$'`: "`$'`" returns everything after the matched string. ([perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html))

```
my $str = 'axxxghdfx445';
$str =~ /x/;

# $' contains '445';
print $';
```

However, there is a cost (emphasis mine):

> WARNING: Once Perl sees that you need one of $&, "$`", or "$'" anywhere
>   in the program, it has to provide them for every pattern match.  This
>   may substantially slow your program.  Perl uses the same mechanism to
>   produce $1, $2, etc, so you also pay a price for each pattern that
>   contains capturing parentheses.  (To avoid this cost while retaining
>   the grouping behaviour, use the extended regular expression "(?: ... )"
>   instead.)  But if you never use $&, "$`" or "$'", then patterns without
>   capturing parentheses will not be penalized.  **So avoid $&, "$'", and
>   "$`" if you can, but if you can't (and some algorithms really
>   appreciate them), once you've used them once, use them at will, because
>   you've already paid the price.**  As of 5.005, $& is not so costly as the
>   other two.

But wait, there's more! You get two operators for the price of one, act NOW!

> As a workaround for this problem, Perl 5.10.0 introduces
>   "${^PREMATCH}", "${^MATCH}" and "${^POSTMATCH}", which are equivalent
>   to "$`", $& and "$'", except that they are only guaranteed to be
>   defined after a successful match that was executed with the "/p"
>   (preserve) modifier.  The use of these variables incurs no global
>   performance penalty, unlike their punctuation char equivalents, however
>   at the trade-off that you have to tell perl when you want to use them.

```
my $str = 'axxxghdfx445';
$str =~ /x/p;

# ${^POSTMATCH} contains '445';
print ${^POSTMATCH};
```

I would humbly submit that this route is the best and most straight-forward
approach in most cases, since it does not require that you do special things
with your pattern construction in order to retrieve the postmatch portion, and there
is no performance penalty.

Comment: Except you are catching the first occurance of 'x', not the last.

Comment: @runrig: lol, way to derail my entire thesis :)  Indeed, in this particular case, `/x([^x]*)$/` would be better... I got too caught up in describing `$'`, which everyone else had overlooked.

Comment: If you put a '\' before the '`' character you can avoid the code style in the middle of your quote.

Answer (score 2):

**Regular Expression** : `/([^x]+)$/`  `#assuming x is not last element of the string.`