# Select all consecutive lines starting with ".", except last one

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So I'm cleaning up a text file full of folders and documents that leaked somewhere. My point is to use regex to ease my job of finding if anything of ours has been compromised (obviously, it has).
I already got rid of some 80% of the junk that ain't ours, but suddenly I was left with a lot of empty folders on the listing. Since they start with "." and the empty ones are consecutive, here I am.

One example would be:

```
./folder1/folder2/folder3:
./folder1/folder2/folder4:
./folder1/folder2/folder5:
-rwxr-xr-x  1    514K  3 Out 08:06 somefilename.here
```

And my goal is to remove the first and second lines. Bear with me, the original files has over 15k lines, the cleaned up was left with some 3k. So there isn't just these two lines to remove, but they fit the profile perfectly.

I was thinking about something like `(^\..*\n)+\.`, but it still selects the last line, and I want that to stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google gave me some ideas like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203365/python-regex-matching-all-but-last-occurrence), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115976/regex-matching-all-but-last-occurence-of-character) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439123/how-can-i-match-everything-that-is-after-the-last-occurrence-of-some-char-in-a-p) last one, but I don't know if my regex-fu is still weak, I couldn't grasp. Then I stumbled on [this](https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/470104-regular-expression-match-all-except-last-one#post1807875) other one:

```
pattern = /df(?=.)/g;
```

and it hit me to try out `(^\..*\n)+(?=\.)`, and it was done!